# Image position changing on device to device in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, cordova, html5-canvas

I have one background image(City image) with scroll, on that image I am placing some small images(Just like bomb images on the city image). I have canvas width and height depending on these variables I am placing the bomb image on the city image. When I place the bomb image at can.width/2 and can.height/2 in 430*300 devices, image will be on the center but when I try testing on bigger screen mobile, bomb image position is changing. I need to place bomb image in the same location for all devices. When I zoom in also position is changing. Anybody please help me to solve this scenario.

Here is my code

```
  function smallBombImg(){
document.getElementById('carImg1').style.top = can.width/2 +"px";
document.getElementById('carImg1').style.left = can.height/2 +"px";
//document.getElementById('carImg1').style.background-attachment = "fixed";
document.getElementById('carImg1').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('carImg1').src = 'img/bomb1.png';
    }
```

HTML code is here

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="can"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="btn">  
    <input type="image" id="zoomIn" src="img/up.png" onclick="zoomIn()" />
    <input type="image" id="zoomOut" src="img/down.png"
        onclick="zoomOut()" />
</div>
<div id="score">
    <p id="scoreCount">
        <b></b>
    </p>
</div>
<div>


<img alt="simple1" id="carImg1" style="position: absolute; display: none;" /> 




</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You will need to get screen measurements from the window object and take those into account. You can set an event listener on the window resize event (this is trivial with jQuery, not so sure about vanilla javascript) and re-position your image when the screen is zoomed/resized.

Comment: @francisco.preller Thanks for reply.. Sounds good but Im very beginner in Jquery and JS. I am not getting how to do it? Can u please give one example?

Comment: @user2092317 I am doing it dynamically, I don't want to place explicitly in center, left, right and all.

Comment: Hope the answer helps, can't stick around long, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I have to be brief, I am very sorry but I am running late.

Using jQuery:

```
var windowEventTimeoutEnded;

$(window).resize(function() {

    clearTimeout(windowEventTimeoutEnded);
        $(window).height(); // gets the height of the window
        $(window).width(); // gets the width of the window

    // This ensures the below does not trigger until the resize event is finished
    windowEventTimeoutEnded = setTimeout(function() { 

        // Perform your resizing math and logic here, such
        canvas.css({
            width: 1234,
            height: 235,
            position: 'absolute' // etc, etc, etc
        })

    }, 500 );

});
```

Sorry for the brevity, hope this helps. I will return later and check if this helped and add to it if necessary, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will check this. Give me some time

Comment: I have consider the window height and width for all devices and background image is having scrolling feature so when I scroll it then window width and height is increasing so bomb image position is also changing. How to fix them dynamically